# fail to create a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

`enter code here`Im a new to rails and I faced such probem. Here is an error

```
No route matches {:action=>"open", :controller=>"messages", :conversation_id=>"6", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

here is controller action

```
before_action :set_conversation, except:[:open]
before_action :set_message, only:[:open]

def open
  @message.open!
  respond_with @message
end

def set_conversation
  @conversation = Conversation.includes(:messages).find(params[:conversation_id])
end

def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:body)
end
```

And a view

```
-elsif !message.opened?
  .nontouch id="mess_#{message.id}"           
    =link_to 'Open', open_message_path(id: message.id), method: :patch, remote: true, class:'btn btn-success'
```

Here is route

```
resources :conversations do    
  resources :messages, shallow: true do
    patch :open, on: :member
  end
end
```

I need some help on that. Where am I wrong? If any additional info is needed let me know

```
rake routes | grep open
open_message PATCH  /messages/:id/open(.:format)                    messages#open
```

removing shallow from routing and editing link like this

```
  =link_to 'Open', open_conversation_message_path(message.conversation.id, message.id), method: :patch, remote: true, class:'btn btn-success'
```

gives

```
No route matches {:action=>"open", :controller=>"messages", :conversation_id=>"6", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Comment: Can you add `rake routes | grep open` output?

Comment: rake routes | grep open
            open_message PATCH  /messages/:id/open(.:format)                           messages#open

Comment: I also updated question

Comment: your `message.id` is null in view. Since `open` is a member action, it needs to have a valid id(non null)

Comment: remove `shallow: true` from routes

Comment: when I set somth like =message.id before the link - it shows a valid Id. But it does not show it it my link (

Comment: @ Oleg Sobchuk  Yep, that would work, but I dont need to set conversation_id to actions like update and show etc. I whant it to work with shallow/

Comment: have you tried `open_message_path(message)` ?

Comment: @ rebagliatte  yes. unforunately that wont work ((

Comment: @Oleg Sobchuk actually removing shalow does not work also/. I updated a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **button_to** instead of a link.

> Generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL created by the set of options. This is the safest method to ensure links that cause changes to your data are not triggered by search bots or accelerators.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to

---

**In your view:**

```
<%= button_to "Open", { action: 'open', id: message.id }, method: :patch, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
```

With this approach you can keep your routes.rb file as it originally was:

```
resources :conversations do    
  resources :messages, shallow: true do
    patch :open, on: :member
  end
end
```

Comment: I recieve No route matches {:action=>"open", :controller=>"messages", :conversation_id=>"6", :id=>nil} when using button

Comment: @anti-k are you sure `shallow: true` is still there?

Comment: Give me a minute? I'll try once more///

Comment: It's very odd that your error messages includes the `conversation_id` bits when using `shallow: true`. Is your project open source? Please post a link to its github repo if it is.

Comment: yep sure! Tanks alot !  Just a minute, Ill commit changes and give you a link

Comment: here is my repo https://github.com/anti-k-camino/ticketsua  trouble view is in _message.html.slim

Comment: I commited to my repo, so If you can, Ill be very thankful for some help

Comment: @anti-k the problem is that `message.id` is `nil` since the `message` is a new record.

Comment: Oh yes! That is it!! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

i tried build next routes

```
resources :conversations do
  resources :messages do
    patch :open, on: :member
  end
end
```

this return me:

```
$ rake routes | grep open
open_conversation_message PATCH     /conversations/:conversation_id/messages/:id/open(.:format) messages#open
```

it means that you try to work with specific message from specific cinversation

and currently you have to build your path like `open_conversation_message_path(@conversation, @message)` (with method PATCH)

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"open", :controller=>"messages", :conversation_id=>"6", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: I have removed shallow true and edited link like this =link_to "Open", open_conversation_message_path(@conversation, @message), method: patch, remote: true

Comment: can you check path in rails console? type in console `app.open_conversation_message_path(1, 2)`

Comment: I removed shallow, and tryed in console, I recieve  => "/conversations/1/messages/2/open"

Comment: it means that this route valid, and now ensure that `@conversation` and `@message` really exist

Comment: Ok Il try... I have a collection of messages so I use _message partial ...

Answer (score 0):

So here is what worked `= button_to "Open", { action: 'open', id: "#{message.id}" }, method: :patch, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-success'`
It was needed to interpolate #{message.id}